# how to get date string in format dd.MM from datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how to get date string in format dd.MM from datetime in T-SQL.
Example
20.03 from 20.03.2019

Comment: Tag the the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Column data type? You should use proper `date` data type!

Answer (score 0):

`20.03.2019` is not a standard date format assuming it is in string format so, you can use `left()`  :

```
select left('20.03.2019', 5)
```

Comment: from datetime but not from string

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use the format function.

```
format('20.03.2019','dd.MM')
```